# Getting NullPointerException while performing getText alert handling

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
String alreadyuploaded="Mentioned upload file has already been uploaded";

String msg= DriverUtility.waitForAlertMsg(driver);
if(msg!= null && msg.contains("Wrong")|| msg.contains("Duplicate")|| msg.contains(alreadyuploaded))
{
    System.out.println("Invalid Receipt Upload or already uploaded");
    //      FinnoneOpration.ReceiptFlag=false;
    Alert alert1 = driver.switchTo().alert();
    System.out.println("alert1 text using  file upload is::"+alert1);
    alert1.accept();
    Thread.sleep(1000); 
    driver.close();
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM iedriverserver.exe /F");
}
```

Comment: I am not seeing any .getText() method in the query.

Comment: Can you provide the error message as well?

Answer (score 0):

If the alert is not displayed or accessable, *driver.switchTo().alert()* will return null and *alert1.accept();* will raise a NullPointException.

If that's the case, *waitForAlertMsg* may have some problem.